# How would you make this simple stereoscopic gif, with no camera, or video footage in Photoshop, or After Effects CC? Only needs to be 2-6 frames

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

[image]

Hey! I was wondering if any of you could reverse engineer this for me or give me a simple break down of how I could manipulate 1 still image to do this effect, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! What have you tried so far? What problems have you ran up against? What articles have you looked at? Showing effort is likely to get you better answers

Comment: You can't reverse a GIF made from two images into one image. To make these images, you need the original two stereoscopic photos to work with (or spend a LOT of time redrawing the second frame)

Answer (score 1):

It's 2 images at different angles. The animation just toggles between the two images. The use of 2 cameras is preferred because you can capture the *exact* same moment from different angles.

Without a camera, and if you only have 1 image... you need to create the second image. Creating an exact duplicate image at a different angle can be quite a daunting task and not explained easily without seeing the original image. Simply transforming one image is probably *never* going to give adequate results. You'll be able to "fake" it but it won't actually work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is correct, there is one app on the apple store that has the stereoscopic 3D gif effect (jittergram), BUT it's only simulated and you would have to compensate for it.

As for photoshop only... [see this video](http://thecreatorsproject.vice.com/blog/learn-how-to-make-stereoscopic-gifs), it's possible you can use the same technique to create different effects.

Answer (score 0):

Camera setting on continuous shot, shift weight from left foot to right foot while shooting continuous shots to get the 3D perspective. Stack them in a gif editor of any kind and bam you've got your stereoscopic gif

Comment: Can you please elaborate? (for users who don't necessarily understand all those terms)